# Writing 2D points in XML format

Tags: xml

While writing an array of 2D points in XML I get the following output:

```
<Vertices count="42">
  <V>
    <X>110</X>
    <Y>0</Y>
  </V>
  <V>
    <X>109.5105</X>
    <Y>3.0901</Y>
  </V>
  <V>
    <X>108.0901</X>
    <Y>5.8778</Y>
  </V>
  ...
```

Internally we are discussing on what is the best layout/tag naming for writing them. Here are other few options:

```
<Vertices>
  <Point>110, 0</Point>
  <Point>109.5105, 3.0901</Point>
  <Point>108.0901, 5.8778</Point>
  ...
```

or

```
<Vertices>
  <item>110, 0</item>
  <item>109.5105, 3.0901</item>
  <item>108.0901, 5.8778</item>
  ...
```

Suppose you'll need to parse this XML file:

- What layout would you like most?
- What layout is more correct according to XML specifications?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is highly opinion-based, so here's mine:

I'd go for the first approach for several reasons:

1. This data format is probably used internally only, so it doesn't matter whether it is pretty or not, as long as it is machine readable.
2. It is easily extensible. Want a Z-Coordinate? Well, add another element. This is possible *without breaking existing functionality*! This means that a version of your application that requires a Z-Coordinate can still read an XML file that does not contain it and assume Z as 0. A version of your application that can not handle a Z-Coordinate will simply ignore it.
3. It is easily validatable. You can assume every coordinate to contain a float value, which can be validated using standard means like [XSD](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_intro.asp). The other formats require more knowledge about the content of each element, which may not be included in standard tools.

Another option in formatting could be this:

```
<vertices>
    <vertex x="0.123" y="1.443" />
    <vertex x="1.321" y="0.334" />
</vertices>
```

The same list of advantages is true for this format, only that it is easier to read for humans.

---

EDIT: I forgot that for parsing it is much easier with your first suggestion (and the one I gave above) than the other two formats you suggested, which require another string splitting/trimming operation for each point.

Comment: What about the `count=42` attribute? Shall we include it?

Comment: It just leads to problems. Imagine someone removing nodes manually without updating the attribute. Also, what's the point of that attribute? You can easily count the number of vertices after or even while parsing the XML file. Using `XmlDocument` this is a no-brainer.

Comment: Please also note that the XML specification does not make any statement about the order in which nodes are read! Most XML parsers I know will return nodes in the order they are in the XML file, but that's not a given, so if the order of the vertices is relevant, you need another attribute you can sort by after parsing the XML file.