# Writing a grid of 2D points in XML format

Tags: c#, .net, xml

What layout to write a multidimensional array of items is more correct according to XML specifications?

This one:

```
<Points>
  <Row index="0">
    <V>
      <X>110</X>
      <Y>0</Y>
    </V>
    <V>
      <X>109.5105</X>
      <Y>3.0901</Y>
    </V>
  </Row>
  <Row index="1">
    <V>
      <X>110</X>
      <Y>0</Y>
    </V>
    <V>
      <X>109.5105</X>
      <Y>3.0901</Y>
    </V>
  </Row>
  ...
```

or this one?

```
<Points rows="4" columns="2">
    <V>
      <X>110</X>
      <Y>0</Y>
    </V>
    <V>
      <X>109.5105</X>
      <Y>3.0901</Y>
    </V>
    <V>
      <X>110</X>
      <Y>0</Y>
    </V>
  ...
```

Thanks.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38197743/writing-2d-point-in-xml-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the literal xml specification, both of those are equally correct.  The xml spec doesn't care about the specific use of the xml, only that it is well formed (all tags closed, no scrambled begin / tags for multiple elements, etc).

As far as creating a scheme for your own data goes, I would pick the one that most closely matches the format of the underlying data as the user of your scheme needs to deal with it.

With your specific example, is the data presented as one contiguous list that that only has rows and columns as "calculated" values, or is it represented as a list of lists of points?  You would want to pick the format that most closely represents how it is used.

---

Some extra notes:

- Your first format would allow for a jagged grid, where each row can
  have a varying number of points.
- The second format enforces an exact
  rectangular shape.

Comment: Maybe I could drop the `index="0"` attribute so the file could be changed manually adding and removing a row?

Comment: If the file is meant to be user editable, I would probably remove that also.  Just keep in mind that the order of sibling nodes is not guaranteed by the XML spec, so the parser can return them in any order it wants.  However, I have **never** encountered a parser that returns them in a different order than they were listed, so it should be safe.